# smtp server counld not send mail in zend 2

Tags: email, zend-framework, procedure

I have am using an SMTP mail server. When I register a new user, I recieve the following error message:

An error occurred
Could not open socket
Additional information:
Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException
File:
C:\wamp\www\zendtest\vendor\zendframework\zend-mail\src\Protocol\AbstractProtocol.php:209
Message:
Could not open socket
What should I do?

Comment: Please complete your question respecting [the MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) So we can help you. From what you gave us here, we can't really investigate on your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to wamp->php->php.ini open this file and find ssl.dll after that remove ; symbol from starting of line. then save the file and restart the wamp. This is working for me.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.